# change the mouse cursor to a Wait icon and prevent the user from clicking on any controls

Tags: jquery, cursor

I am using ASP.NET in C#. I have a Master page. My problem is how to change the mouse cursor to a wait cursor when the page is loading? and also to prevent the user from clicking on any controls.

Are there any ideas ? because I have been trying the hourglass, but still when a page is loading the user still can clicking on any controls.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the controls if they are inputs by adding the "disabled" attribute to the input tags.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //remove the disabled attribute from all relevant inputs
    $(elements).removeAttr('disabled');
    //Then change the cursor back to the default
    $('body').css('cursor' , 'default');
});
```